# How to count the number of objects created in php app?

Tags: php

My question is quite simple: **How to get the total of the objects created during execution of php application?**

The value should be precise based on user input. So, addition of "new" + "clone" in source code is not appropriate variant.

Comment: There is no PHP function to get number of created objects.

Comment: All objects there where ever created during the lifetime of the script? Peak number of object in memory at once? Why is this number relevant exactly?

Comment: @Charlotte Dunois 
Maybe some low-level profilers or reverse engineering tools are present?

Comment: You can try XDebug profiling, but not sure if it counts the number of objects created...

Comment: @deceze, I'm looking for good options to reverse engineer the source codes. I'm trying to find my way seperating big problem into parts.

Comment: Here is your php source code https://github.com/php/php-src